# Select showing up weird on mac

Tags: html, css, angular, select, css-selectors

I have an issue where the language selector "Deutsch" in the image below is behaving weird on a mac. Basically the options are showing up in the upper left corner instead of underneath it.

[image]

```
<select class="language-select">
  <option value="de" class="ng-star-inserted"> Deutsch </option>
  <option value="en" class="ng-star-inserted"> English </option>
</select>
```

The code above is the html structure from the browser.
The styles of the list that is part of the hamburger menu is done via flexbox:

```
display: flex;
align-items: flex-start;
justify-content: center;
flex-direction: column;
gap: 15px;
```

Any help would be apreciated!

Edit: It works fine if I don't enter on responsive mode in the browser. If I open the Responsive view, it breaks on any/all resolutions/screen sizes.

Oddly enough I created a codepen with the html structure and styles, and in codepen it looks as it should on any screen size: https://codepen.io/torjescu-sergiu/pen/yLqVNVX?editors=1100

Comment: This is OS-dependent.  The browser does not style it, the OS does.  Can't be more help, I don't have a MAC

Comment: Yeah, I figured it is OS related, but hoping there is some kind of solution for it. Unfortunatelly I need to use the select and cannot change it to something else in the html.

Comment: If you edit the question and use the snippet tool `<>` to post your html and css, then others can see and try it for themselves.  Assuming they have a MAC.

Comment: I will try to recreate it in codepen